# Selenium Chrome Webdriver SessionNotCreatedException for Linux Image on ARM MacBook

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Given the following base image:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.11-slim-buster AS base

WORKDIR /app

# Install Google Chrome
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install curl gnupg -y && \
    curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq install google-chrome-stable && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install selenium=="4.12.0" && pip install selenium-wire=="5.1" && pip install webdriver-manager=="4.0"

CMD sleep infinity
```

I launch the image through Docker on my MacBook with an M1 chip (ARM architecture). I `exec` into the container and try to run the following

```py
from typing import TypeAlias
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
Driver: TypeAlias = webdriver.Remote | webdriver.Chrome

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-application-cache")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
    options=chrome_options,
)
```

which leads to the following error message

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x00400075cfb3 <unknown>
#1 0x0040004304a7 <unknown>
#2 0x004000463c93 <unknown>
#3 0x00400046010c <unknown>
#4 0x0040004a2ac6 <unknown>
#5 0x004000499713 <unknown>
#6 0x00400046c18b <unknown>
#7 0x00400046cf7e <unknown>
#8 0x0040007228d8 <unknown>
#9 0x004000726800 <unknown>
#10 0x004000730cfc <unknown>
#11 0x004000727418 <unknown>
#12 0x0040006f442f <unknown>
#13 0x00400074b4e8 <unknown>
#14 0x00400074b6b4 <unknown>
#15 0x00400075c143 <unknown>
#16 0x004002738fa3 start_thread
```

Note that these paths exists and seems to be compatible to me.

```
root@843dd9aa6de0:/app# /usr/bin/google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 118.0.5993.70
root@843dd9aa6de0:/app# /opt/google/chrome/chrome --version
Google Chrome 118.0.5993.70 unknown
```

Also, trying to run the Python script locally on my MacBook works (although the installation folder for Chrome and ChromeDriver differs of course). Any ideas how to fix this and what the reason for the failure is?